# Как сделать интеграцию c++ (или python) в QML для QtDesignStudio?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

QtDesignStudio генерирует qmlproject и при нажатии кнопки run запускает его через qmlscene. Соответственно qmlRegisterType() тут не запустится.

Как добавить QObject чтоб был доступен в QtDesignStudio?

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить QtObject в QML, пример:

```
QtObject {
    id: values

    // property values to simulate
    property int name1: 5
    property string name2: "foo"
    property real name3: 2.5

}
```

Более подробную информацию можно узнать в [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/studio-javascript.html)

Comment: а сиплюсплюсный код он как выполнять будет?)

Comment: @eri Qt Design Studio не исполняет код на С++. Для симуляции работы используются заготовленные данные.